# Misplaced subviews in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm adding a few subviews to a `UIScrollView` and setting its contentSize, like this:

```
let cellWidth: CGFloat = 100.0
let cellHeight: CGFloat = 100.0

for i in 0...10 {
    let view: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * cellWidth,  0, cellWidth, cellHeight))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
    self.scrollView.addSubview(view)
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(10 * cellWidth, cellHeight)
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I don't really understand why these subviews aren't drawn at y=0

There are no constraints applied in the storyboard to this UIScrollView.

Comment: I had a same problem once...then what I do is make a view and add scrollview as a subview and it works perfectly...

Comment: in `viewDidAppear:`, check what is the value of `contentInset` of your scroll view. If it is non-zero than set it to zero value. or try this [option](http://mokagio.github.io/tech-journal/2015/01/23/ios-unexpected-table-view-header-padding.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason for this.

For anyone with the same problem, just go to interface builder and select the troubling UIViewController.

In the 'Attributes Inspector' section, on the right pane, untick 'Adjust Scroll View Insets'.